# Pass Javascript Function to Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to pass a function as a parameter to a plugin.

Problem: I am creating a jquery plugin. The jquery plugin makes the JSON-P calls.

The part of the code:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.GetJsonResult = function (options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.GetJsonResult.defaults, options);

    var control = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: opts.url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("Error occured textStatus=" + textStatus + " errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
       },
        success: function (j) {

       }

    });

}

})(jQuery);
```

Can i pass some function name that will execute in the success method when JSOn request is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the function itself:

```
$(x).GetJsonResult({
    success: function() { /* ... */ }
});
```

Or:

```
function pancakes() { /* ... */ }

$(x).GetJsonResult({
    success: pancakes
});
```

And then:

```
$.fn.GetJsonResult = function (options) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(j) {
            // Do whatever you need to do.
            if(options.success)
                options.success();
        }
    });
    // ...
};
```

Comment: i dont know that we call the function like  success: pancakes. So now I put the function as a variable and pass it in a plugin as a option and put it in success method.